# Android GPS isn't providing updates anymore

Tags: android, gps

My own android app isn't providing me with anymore GPS location updates. I've tried to build the simplest app possible and it's still not working. There's a blinking GPS icon in the status bar (so the GPS can't be turned off correct?), however I don't get locationChanged updates.

I have absolutely no clue what the problem is.

Manifest includes this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Mainactivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    TextView textView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
    }

    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                textView.setText(location.getLatitude() + "  " + location.getLongitude());
        }
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {        }
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change Activity to also implement LocationListener.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements LocationListener{
```

take the functions out of inner class, change the locationListener to this.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0
         , this); //note changed last parameter to this.
}
//The following methods were inside the inner class.  They were not created in time 
//for oncreate to requestLocationUpdates.
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            textView.setText(location.getLatitude() + "  " 
            + location.getLongitude());
    }
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {        }
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {        }
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {        }
```

Try that and see if it works better.  The Activity itself is now a LocationListener, and the updates will come to this class.

Comment: unfortunately it's still not working. I have no idea why.

Somehow Google Maps is still working correct though. It might be using more information than GPS to decide on my location

Comment: Is your permission in the Android Manifest outside the <application /> block, you need it outside that block.  In my code it is after the close application. Before </manifest>

Comment: Yes it's inside the manifest tags but outside the application

Comment: can you copy what is in your MainActivity.java to a comment back to me here?  I'll check it out, and edit my answer if I find anything.  Thanks.  Also I've got to ask, are you indoors?  I get terrible GPS reception indoors.  The other thing I can think of is, does your device have a GPS receiver?  Some tablets don't.